# Installation of python distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, miniconda

I am new to python and using Windows 10. I need to install a Python distribution. I know that there are many implementations of Python. I am narrowing my focus to three of them: CPython, Anaconda, Miniconda(basically anaconda without extra packages). I know that CPython ships with pip as package manager. Whereas anaconda and miniconda ship with both pip and conda.
I have read some things on the internet regarding which one to prefer but I got even more confused.
Please give me the pros and cons of each approach installing only CPython/Anaconda/Miniconda, as well as what problems I can face with them in the long run.
Also please tell if it is safe to install both CPython and Miniconda on the same machine because I have read somewhere that installing two different versions of python on a machine(not in different virtual environments) can lead to conflicts with system python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are just starting with Python, I would suggest using Anaconda.** It supplies a lot of support and many of the useful packages, whereas (as you mentioned) Miniconda does not have as many.

And to your point, multiple Python installs can be very annoying. You will run into conflicts between environments and packages that can really frustrate you.

I think there is some confusion on the roll of CPython, though. Miniconda and Anaconda are *distributions* of Python; CPython is an *implementation* of Python. In fact, Anaconda (and I believe Miniconda) actually distribute CPython (the most common implementation), as compared to other versions, such as Jython and IronPython.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry used the incorrect terminology.  I meant the distribution available at python.org